# How to hide rows in a Grid in The Master Page Header based on data returned and displayed on the page

Tags: birt

I have a requirement to show a different header based on the content.

The header is a combination of logos and accompanying text that goes with the logo.

I need to display Company A logo or Company B Logo based on the data on the page.

The actuall content is a simple letter to the employee withe a few dynamic fields. There is a page break for every employee. The dataset contains  the company name which drive the determination of the logo.

I tried a few things and was unsuccessful.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best idea is to *not* display the logo in the master page.
Instead, make the logo part of a group header with "repeat header" selected.